# copyhere doesn't respect overwrite parameter in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing a VBA code to add files, which are into several folders, into a ZIP file. 
This procedure should run automatically, by a scheduled job, and I try to add a parameter to force "yes to all". 
In [Microsoft support](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176633.aspx) there are some constants but if I add to my code, I don't have the aspected result.
the code is the following

```
Public Sub ZipFolder(ZipFileName As Variant, _
                    FolderPath As Variant, _
                    Optional ByVal FileFilter As String, _
                    Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = False)

Dim fso As Object, tf As Object
Dim strZIPHeader As String, sFile As String

On Error GoTo done
' create zip file header
strZIPHeader = Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        sFile = Dir(FolderPath, vbNormal)
        Do Until sFile = vbNullString
            .Namespace(ZipFileName).CopyHere FolderPath & sFile, **"&H10&"**
            sFile = Dir
        Loop
    End With


Set fso = Nothing
Set tf = Nothing
done:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbApplicationModal + vbInformation
End Sub
```

The parameter &H10& doesn't work. I have tried with "&0X14&" as well but same result.
Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: I assume you've just added `**` around it to try and highlight the code in the question? That doesn't work in a code block so you may be better editing the question to change it back to your exact code. Also does the actual code have quotes? They shouldn't be required and you probably just want `&H10` which might be what your problem is.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense to me. You're setting a string equal to a zip file header, but you aren't writing that to a file. Also, using `.CopyHere` to include files in a zip file is unsupported (though it tends to work). Please provide the full code, and the current result.

Comment: When reading your question again, I'm not sure if you try to overwrite or not to overwrite files (adding files only) in the zip file.

Comment: Where did you find that crippled code, or was it crippled by yourself?

Comment: Peter, for sure the '**'  has been added by me just to higlight the ponit.

Comment: I've forgotten to delete the part with "' create zip file header
strZIPHeader = Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))" which, as Erik was writng about. By the way, I've solved the problem to skip the files already added onto the ZIP file and the procedure works well now. Thank you Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can study the article and full code here on exactly this subject:

[Zip and unzip files and folders with VBA the Windows Explorer way](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31130/Zip-and-unzip-files-and-folders-with-VBA-the-Windows-Explorer-way.html)

You'll see, that shall the file be overwritten, it is simply deleted before proceeding:

```
    If FileSystemObject.FileExists(ZipFile) Then
        If Overwrite = True Then
            ' Delete an existing file.
            FileSystemObject.DeleteFile ZipFile, True
            ' At this point either the file is deleted or an error is raised.
        Else
            ZipBase = FileSystemObject.GetBaseName(ZipFile)
            ' Modify name of the zip file to be created to preserve an existing file:
            '   "Example.zip" -> "Example (2).zip", etc.
            Version = Version + 1
            Do
                Version = Version + 1
                ZipFile = FileSystemObject.BuildPath(ZipPath, ZipBase & Format(Version, " \(0\)") & ZipExtension)
            Loop Until FileSystemObject.FileExists(ZipFile) = False Or Version > MaxZipVersion
            If Version > MaxZipVersion Then
                ' Give up.
                Err.Raise ErrorPathFile, "Zip Create", "File could not be created."
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I've forgotten to delete the part with "' create zip file header strZIPHeader = Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))" which, as Erik was writng about. By the way, I've solved the problem to skip the files already added onto the ZIP file and the procedure works well now as per Gustav suggest. Thank you Guys.

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.